# How can I set the bootstrap switcher by default to ON?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, switchers

I am using the Bootstrap Switcher (https://bttstrp.github.io/bootstrap-switch/examples.html)

```
<p><input  type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-on-color="info" ></p>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/highlight.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-switch"></script>
<script src="js/main_switch.js"></script>
```

By default it looks like this:

[image]

But I would like the switcher to be default switched to ON:

[image]

But even if I set it to checked, it is always OFF. I also tried:

```
<p><input  type="checkbox" data-on-color="info" checked></p>
```

But no change.

I also tried:

```
<p><input  type="checkbox" data-on-color="info" checked="true"></p>
```

but no change

Comment: According to the docs and online demo, the checked attribute is all that's necessary, so please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. Also, the docs say any buttons need `data-toggle="switch"`

Comment: Looks like you need to use a radio: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: `data-toggle="switch"`

code: `<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" checked>`

test: https://jsfiddle.net/u38tq2r9/